# How to style mapboxgl point source

Tags: mapbox

I have created a simple mapboxgl map, and I am adding a source that contains point data. I am trying to then apply a style to the data. The approach I am taking works well for polygon & line data, but I can't find the magic cartocss that will render points. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/4q1db482/

The reason I do not want to simply use the getJSONSource method for point data is to avoid bringing a large number of vectors into the browser.

The question is two part:
1. How can I apply a style to this data that I have created in Mapbox-studio?
2. Or how can I create a style that will work for some simple point data and push it into the style.layers array? It's a bit cumbersome that 'marker-line-color' cartocss is valid in mapbox studio, but not in mapboxgl. I am trying this:

```
   style.layers.push({
        'id': 'dataSource',
        'source': 'tom',
        'interactivity': 'true',
        'source-layer': 'us-ski',
        'render':{
            'text-field': '{name}',
        },
        'style': {
            'text-color': '#8786e0',
            'text-font': 'Open Sans Semibold, Arial Unicode MS Bold',
            /** This is the style used in mapbox-studio **/
            //"marker-symbol": "monument",
            //'marker-line-color': '#3333FF',
            //'marker-width': '3',
            //'marker-fill': '#8786e0'
        },
        'type': 'symbol'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by modifying the style like this:

```
style.layers.push({
    'id': 'dataSource',
    'source': 'tom',
    'interactivity': 'true',
    'source-layer': 'us-ski',
    'render':{
        'text-field': '{name}',
        "icon-image": "marker-12"
    },
    'style': {
        'text-color': '#8786e0',
        'text-font': 'Open Sans Semibold, Arial Unicode MS Bold',
    },
    'type': 'symbol'
});
```

The key was: "icon-image": "marker-12"